# llenar combobox con con base de datos sqlite en tkinter python

Tags: tkinter, sqlite, combobox

hola gente que tal estoy haciendo una mini ventana para un sistema de ventas donde estoy con un combobox intentando que me aparezcan los empleados para seleccionarlo y decir si es empleado o administrador

la cuestion es que no tengo idea como llenar el combo box con los nombres de los empleados registrados en la base de datos

````
class privilegios:

    db_nombre = 'ProyectoMI.py/BaseDeDatos.db'  # Llamado a la base de datos

    def __init__(self):
        vent_privilegios = Tk()
        vent_privilegios.title("Privilegios")
        vent_privilegios.resizable(0,0)
        vent_privilegios.config(bg="#83D6A8")

        # Centrado de ventana en pantalla
        ox, oy = vent_privilegios.winfo_screenwidth(
        )/2, vent_privilegios.winfo_screenheight()/2
        vent_privilegios.geometry("=500x300+%d+%d" % (ox-550, oy-300))

        empleado = Label(vent_privilegios, text="Empleado: ", font=("arial 18 bold"))
        empleado.config(bg="#83D6A8")
        empleado.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=60, pady=20)

        def combo_input():
            with sqlite3.connect(self.db_nombre) as conn:
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Personal")
                result=cursor.fetchall()
                cursor.commit()
                return result
            raise Exception("No se pudo conectar con la DB")

        combo_list = ttk.Combobox(vent_privilegios)
        combo_list['value'] = combo_input()
        combo_list.pack()

        vent_privilegios.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Hola Maxi, ¿la tabla Personal que columnas tiene?, porque supongo que no querrás mostrarlas todas en el ComboBox pero si que las pides todas en la query.

Comment: hola que tal , tiene id, nombreyapellido, correo, domicilio , etc. si esa que puse ahi es de prueba.. deberia ser SELECT nombre FROM Personal pero no me funciona igual me tira error primero me tira error de unable file  como que no puede abrir el archivo de la base de datos y despues me tira error en el combo_list['value'] = combo_input()

Comment: Vale, eso aclarado, la ruta a la BD es un poco extraña "'ProyectoMI.py/BaseDeDatos.db'" es ¿ProyectoMI.py una carpeta? Lo digo porque la extensión .py me chirría...

Comment: perfecto, si es una carpeta, al momento de crearla le puse sin querer el ".py" y asi quedo (al finalizar tendré que corregir eso )

Comment: ahora quite todo solo deje la tabla y el combo box vacio porque ya se me estaba mezclando todo

Comment: :) vale, las rutas relativas se resuelven en base al directorio de trabajo del script ¿la carpeta ProyectoMI.py contiene tanto a BaseDeDatos.db como al script que muestras? Si no, ¿cual es la estructura?

Comment: Exacto, adentro de la carpeta ProyectoMI.py tengo BaseDeDatos.db y Privilegios.py, asi tambien tengo el Main.py que uso para ejecutarlo simplemente

Comment: se entendió ?  me parece que no fui muy claro con la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes probar con este codigo, y me comentas si te ayudo, saludos

```
def conectbd(self,query):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_nombre) as conn:
         cursor = conn.cursor()
         cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Personal")
         result=cursor.fetchall()
         cursor.commit()
    return result

def combo_input(self):
    query = 'SELECT nombre FROM Personal'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    data=[]
    for rows in db_rows:
        data.append(rows[0])
    return data
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]